# Workaround for broken search?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search, search-results

My company has SharePoint 2010 Foundation. The search function is broken and a fix is a couple months out. I am just a user but I want to be able to find my reports. Is there any way to search for documents using something other than SharePoint's search utility, for example using Google (similar to the search "site:http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com broken" to look for items containing "broken" on the present website)? Happy to use any free outside tool that can work from my own machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you have fixed your search problem. There are 3rd party options but for those you have invested a lot in term of time, resource and money. For example, if you want to google search in your farm then you have to use the google appliance.

http://www.searchtechnologies.com/technology

Another workaround may help little, Filter on your list / library to get the required data.